# Kerberos error when connecting to Oracle database in .NET Core

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, odp.net

I have an application created using .NET Core 3.1 which needs to connect to an Oracle database, the connection code is very straightforward and I'm connecting using a username and password:

```
var con = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($"User Id={env.UserName};Password={env.UserPassword};Data Source={env.TNSName}")
conn.Open();
```

However the `Open()` fails with the following error:

```
{"NA  Kerberos5: 
Authentication handshake failure at stage: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP, Version=2.0.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'. 
The system cannot find the file specified."}
```

Adding a reference to the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP.dll` (both 32 and 64 bit versions tried) does not resolve the error, it just changes it to the one shown below:

```
{"NA  Kerberos5: 
Authentication handshake failure at stage: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP, Version=2.0.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."}
```

Comment: It took me the best part of a day wading through Oracle documentation to work this out, I've recorded it on stackoverflow in the hope that I can save someone else the pain and also in the hope that there is a better answer out there.

Comment: Well done. I suggest that you accept your own answer - I think you're entitled to the 15 rep for your days work. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is that the Managed ODP.NET package for .NET Core does not yet support Kerberos authentication and is unlikely to do so before .NET Core 5 when Microsoft will add the required Kerberos APIs to .NET Core.  This is discussed on the Oracle site [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4288468).

You **only** get this error when the Oracle installation is configured to use Kerberos, usually by setting [SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2035) to 'all' (or maybe'kerberos5').  When this is set to `all` kerberos5 is in the first tier of authentication methods to try so ODP.NET tries to load the Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP assembly that provides the interface to the Kerberos authentication and there isn't a version of this that will work with .NET Core.

The only solution I have come up with for this is to change the SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES value so that Kerberos is not required and one way to do this is to use the OracleConfiguration methods:

```
    OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices = "none";
    var con = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($"User Id={env.UserName};Password={env.UserPassword};Data Source={env.TNSName}")
    conn.Open();
```

This then stops ODP.NET from trying to load the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP.dll` and the connection proceeds.  This does mean that if you actually **want** Kerberos authentication in your .NET Core application you are out of luck until at least [November 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) and maybe longer as Microsoft have to provide the APIs and Oracle then have to build on top of them.

**EDIT** As of April 2022 this still hasn't been resolved and shows no sign of being resolved.  Microsoft has closed the request to create the needed library and Oracle show no sign of wanting to pick this up.  If you want Kerberos and Oracle then you can't use .NET Core.

**EDIT Feb 2023**
There may finally be some movement on this, this page on GitHub suggests that Microsoft and Oracle and now working to resolve the issue [Support for Kerberos Authentication For Oracle DB in .Net Core #237](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/237). This thread now concludes with the following:

> Oracle and MS have concluded our ODP.NET Core Kerberos.NET support
> discussion. Official Oracle support will begin with ODP.NET Core
> 21.10.

Comment: Appreciate the Feb 2023 update

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this error a lot, exact same code was working in all other developers machine and it was heavily used code in large application so adding OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices was not a option.

I was able to fix this by updating sqlnet.ora file at c:\Program Files ()\Oracle_Admin\sqlnet.ora

Updated config

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NONE)

Thanks Jackson for pointing in correct direction.